# What is this code and what should it do?

Tags: java, c#, jquery, vb.net

Question:

What might the following code be expected to do?

```
var notifications = Notification.Query
.Where(n=>n.UserVersion==Oracle.CurrentUserID)
.Where(n=>n.IsUnread==true)
.OrderByDescending
```

My Answer:

Outputs a query result that is stored as variable ‘notifications’ where rows under ‘UserVersion’ field matches with ‘CurrentlUserId’ in Oracle and the ‘IsUnread’ is true. It’s set to order by latest date and onwards and it will display the first 25 rows.

Is this correct? Also what type of programming language is this regarding as I have not across this before.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is 4 unrelated questions rolled into one. You'll probably have better luck asking them all separately and individually tagging them with the appropriate categories.

Comment: Ok, will do that Jmar777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like C# code.  The result isn't really a query result, but rather an `IEnumerable` that contains items from the `Notification.Query` collection that match the criteria specified.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb534855(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Ah ok, got it. And I'm assuming take(25) is definetly show first 25 results?